# SQL Server (running/stopped) Status in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

In the attached image below, I show my SQL Server as seen from SSMS on my PC (left) compared to the same as seen from the server (right) ... could someone advise why the view from my PC does not show the status indicator (running/stopped) for the server and for the SQL Server Agent items?

Also, when you right-click on either of the options, the selection for START|STOP|RESTART are all greyed out....?

For these screenshots, I am connected from my PC with a user account that should have maximum access; under the security settings for this account EVERYTHING is checked.

[image: View of SSMS]

Comment: Hit the refresh button and see if it goes away.

Answer (score 2):

Access to a remote [Service Control Manager (SCM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is subject to OS privileges. W/o SCM privileges you cannot know what services are running, nor can you start or stop any. The required privileges are listed at [Access Rights for the Service Control Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

None of the above is in any way at all related to SQL Server security. Services are controlled by SCM, not SQL Server.